# Ethereum ERC20 trying to Deploy to Alpha Moonbase (Moonbeam Testnet) and I get "Source "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol" not found:"

Tags: ethereum, solidity

My project structure looks like this:

```
contracts
├── CExampleToken.sol
├── compile.js
├── create-eth-wallet.js
├── deploy.js
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
└── node_modules
```

This is my code:

CExampleToken.sol

```
pragma solidity 0.8.9;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Detailed.sol";

contract CExampleToken is ERC20 {
    constructor() ERC20("CExample", "CEXT") {
      _mint(msg.sender, 25000000);
    }
}
```

compile.js

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const solc = require('solc');

const contractPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'CExampleToken.sol');
const source = fs.readFileSync(contractPath, 'utf8');
const input = {
    language: "Solidity",
    sources: {
        'CExampleToken.sol': {
            content: source,
        },
    },
    settings: {
        outputSelection: {
            '*': {
                '*': ['*']
            },
        },
    },
};
const tempFile = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input)));
console.log(tempFile);
const contractFile = tempFile.contracts['CExampleToken.sol']['CExampleToken'];
module.exports = contractFile;
```

deploy.js

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const contractFile = require('./compile');

const bytecode = contractFile.evm.bytecode.object;
const abi = contractFile.abi;
const privKey = <my private key here>;
const address = <my address here>;
const web3 = new Web3('https://rpc.testnet.moonbeam.network');

const deploy = async () => {
    const cexampletoken = new web3.eth.Contract(abi);

    const cexampletokenTx = cexampletoken.deploy({
        data: bytecode,
    });
    
    const createTransaction = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(
        {
            from: address,
            data: cexampletokenTx.encodeABI(),
            gas: '4294967295'
        },
        privKey
    );

    const createReceipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(
        createTransaction.rawTransaction
    );
    console.log("Contract was sucessfully deployed at address: ", createReceipt.contractAddress);
};

deploy();
```

I am trying to compile and deploy by going

```
cd contracts
node deploy.js
```

But I get this error:

```
<myusername>@<mycomputername> contracts % node deploy.js           
{
  errors: [
    {
      component: 'general',
      errorCode: '1878',
      formattedMessage: 'Warning: SPDX license identifier not provided in source file. Before publishing, consider adding a comment containing "SPDX-License-Identifier: <SPDX-License>" to each source file. Use "SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED" for non-open-source code. Please see https://spdx.org for more information.\n' +
        '--> CExampleToken.sol\n' +
        '\n',
      message: 'SPDX license identifier not provided in source file. Before publishing, consider adding a comment containing "SPDX-License-Identifier: <SPDX-License>" to each source file. Use "SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED" for non-open-source code. Please see https://spdx.org for more information.',
      severity: 'warning',
      sourceLocation: [Object],
      type: 'Warning'
    },
    {
      component: 'general',
      errorCode: '6275',
      formattedMessage: 'ParserError: Source "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol" not found: File import callback not supported\n' +
        ' --> CExampleToken.sol:3:1:\n' +
        '  |\n' +
        '3 | import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";\n' +
        '  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n' +
        '\n',
      message: 'Source "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol" not found: File import callback not supported',
      severity: 'error',
      sourceLocation: [Object],
      type: 'ParserError'
    },
    {
      component: 'general',
      errorCode: '6275',
      formattedMessage: 'ParserError: Source "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Detailed.sol" not found: File import callback not supported\n' +
        ' --> CExampleToken.sol:4:1:\n' +
        '  |\n' +
        '4 | import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Detailed.sol";\n' +
        '  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n' +
        '\n',
      message: 'Source "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Detailed.sol" not found: File import callback not supported',
      severity: 'error',
      sourceLocation: [Object],
      type: 'ParserError'
    }
  ],
  sources: {}
}
/Users/<myusername>/Desktop/Coding/CodingTestSpace/MoonbeamTutorial101921/contracts/compile.js:24
const contractFile = tempFile.contracts['CExampleToken.sol']['CExampleToken'];
                                       ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'CExampleToken.sol')
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/<myusername>/Desktop/Coding/CodingTestSpace/MoonbeamTutorial101921/contracts/compile.js:24:40)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/<myusername>/Desktop/Coding/CodingTestSpace/MoonbeamTutorial101921/contracts/deploy.js:2:22)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
<myusername>@<mycomputername> contracts %
```

Btw, I did install openzeppelin. When I made the project I did

1. cd contracts
2. npm init
3. npm install solc@latest
4. npm install @openzeppelin/contracts

What's the problem and how do I fix it?

**UPDATE**
Okay I fixed the problem thanks to @ahmad-gorji
This issue was that the @openzeppelin contracts were using s different compiler so I copied the functions that @openzeppelin was supposed to import directly into my CExampleToken.sol file.

I'm getting a new error now...

```
RuntimeError: abort(Error: Returned error: submit transaction to pool failed: Pool(InvalidTransaction(InvalidTransaction::ExhaustsResources))). Build with -s ASSERTIONS=1 for more info.
at process.abort (/home/Coding/CodingTestSpace/MoonbeamTutorial101921/contracts/node_modules/solc/soljson.js:1:13012)
at process.emit (node:events:390:28)
at emit (node:internal/process/promises:136:22)
at processPromiseRejections (node:internal/process/promises:242:25)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:97:32)
at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:65:3)
at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:526:9)
at processTimers (node:internal/timers:500:7)
myusername@mycompname contracts %
```

I think this might have to do with the moonbeam testnet rpc node though :/. This is the network I'm using in the relevant code.

```
const web3 = new Web3('https://rpc.testnet.moonbeam.network');
```

Comment: I had same problem in Remix too, I copied all openzeppelin contracts and it became OK :(

Comment: I tried that it still didn't work

Comment: What error does it throw when you copy the code?!

Comment: Same exact error as before.

Comment: You got it wrong, I meant I copied all contract code and paste it in a solidity file in Remix

Comment: Now that I copied the code the directory looks like this. https://gist.github.com/ChristianOConnor/d0c2a2654b84c6267dede2ef7dba210b

Comment: Oh how did you do that? I'm using the vscode btw not remix

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238373/discussion-between-ahmad-gorji-and-christianoconnor).